# What is the מסכ"י?

Tags: acronyms

While it is common to find the reshei tevot מס"כ (מסכת: -כלה, -כלאים, -כלים, -כריתות, -כתובות), it is less so to find מסכ"י. For instance, you find this in a phrase like עד כאן לשונו **מסכ"י**. Any takes?

Comment: המסכלת, המסכל׳ (hamaskelet) - 1) Intellectual. 2) Logical

Comment: Shmuel, doesn't it seem a bit odd then that  עד כאן לשונו מסכ"י would then be rendered as "so far the logical/intellectual language"?

Comment: מספר כתב יד (from a manuscript)?

Comment: דאס איז פיל בעסער "so far the language from a manuscript". But I am not 100% sure. Still, yasher koach.

Comment: Ba'alei Brit uses this sometimes, and that context imo doesn't fit: https://www.sefaria.org/Ba'alei_Brit_Avram%2C_Lech_Lecha.2?vhe=Vilna,_1873&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en https://www.sefaria.org/Ba'alei_Brit_Avram%2C_Vayera.4?vhe=Vilna,_1873&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en etc

Comment: By the way, my two sources קובץ ראשי תיבות וקיצורים (אחים גיטלר), אוצר ראשי תיבות (שמואל אשכנזי - דב ירדן) do not have an entry for מסכ"י.

Comment: Yep. I've seen in R' Avraham Azulai too. But it is not common nevertheless.

Comment: Does מסכת יומא work?

Comment: Not really (although it fits), but thanks! I think the best for the particular context is מספר כתב יד "from a manuscriot".

Comment: In the [introduction to Chesed_LeAvraham](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chesed_LeAvraham%2C_Introduction.31), R. Abraham Azulai says: "גם קצת דרושים לקטתי מדברי האלקי האר"י זלה"ה, וזכרתים משמו, וגם מה שלקטתי מקצת ספרי המקובלים **כתבתי מסכ"י ר"ל מספר כתיבת יד**".

Comment: Yep, as I said above about R' Azulai.